# How to subtract a portion of TXT files using Windows Command line?

Tags: powershell, command-line, powerbi, text-processing

I have thousands of TXT files in the following format:

```
<<< content not relevant >>>
<<< content not relevant >>>
<<< content not relevant >>>
Date
25-June-20  VAR1          VAR2          VAR3          VAR4
07:00:00    1.0           2.0           1.1           2.1
08:00:00    2.0           1.2           1.3           3.1
09:00:00    3.0           2.1           2.3           2.1
10:00:00    1.0           1.0           2.1           3.4
<<< content not relevant >>>
<<< content not relevant >>>
<<< content not relevant >>>
<<< content not relevant >>>
```

I need to extract into Power BI only the fields in the middle, excluding the first 3 lines and last 4 lines. I was thinking in using a Windows Command line to cut the unwanted lines and import using "Folder" option in Power BI. Also... the date changes according to TXT file, but not the variable names.

Any suggestion to cut the unwanted lines? Should I take different approach?

Comment: You need a code-expressible way to ignore the "content not relevant" lines in the data. That depends on what the data looks like.

Comment: `Select-Object -?`

Answer (score 1):

Skip the first 3 and last 4 lines?

```
powershell "get-childitem | foreach { get-content $_ | select -skip 3 | select -SkipLast 4 }"
4
5
6
4
5
6
```

Comment: Elegant code! Thanks! how do I apply this to thousands of files in a folder?